# How to Change css element in react

Tags: reactjs, styles

I have below line in react where have written ternary operator to set different class as per condition

```
<div onClick={this.Testfunction.bind(this)}  className={this.state.noteArray.length >0?"Class1":"Class2"}>
```

it work fine but instead of setting Class2 , how can change Class1 element like height

So in Class1 my css is

```
    height: calc(100vh - 30em) !important;
    position: absolute;
    width: 385px;
    right: 147px;
    background: #f3f3f7;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
```

And in Class2 my css is

```
  height: calc(100vh - 70em) !important;
    position: absolute;
    width: 385px;
    right: 147px;
    background: #f3f3f7;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
```

So only change is height so instead of writing different class2 how can only height can be change
this css is reference from different file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this

```
<div onClick={this.Testfunction.bind(this)}  style={{height: this.state.noteArray.length >0 ? "calc(100vh - 30em)" : "calc(100vh - 70em)"}}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height directly with a style tag:

```
<div onClick={this.Testfunction.bind(this)}  className="Class1" style={{height: `calc(100vh - ${this.state.noteArray.length >0?"30em":"70em"}) !important`}}>
```

Since rest of the styles are same in both the classes you can set them in 'Class1'

```
.Class1 {
   position: absolute;
   width: 385px;
   right: 147px;
   background: #f3f3f7;
   z-index: 10;
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
}
```

Comment: tried but it does not worked , shall i set whole css inline ?